# Vertical hangul quote

Tags: hangul

i wanted to get a tattoo of the famous quote "웃어라. 온세상이 너와 함께 웃을 것이다.
울어라. 너 혼자 울 것이다." from the movie Oldboy. Would it still make sense if It was written vertically?

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't make any more or less sense that having it written horizontally. Just remember that in vertical writing the columns go right to left.